# Resonse.Redirect works from VisualStudio but not from IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, hyperlink, logout, response.redirect

I've made a logout link with a asp.net HyperLink, with NavigateUrl="Default.aspx?Logout=1".
In the Default PageLoad I check if the Query string is null if not the session is terminated and the user is redirected to the same page, without the Query string, acting as a login page.

The code in the Default PageLoad is:

```
      if (Request.QueryString["Logout"] != null)
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
            Session.Clear();
            Session.Abandon();
            Response.Redirect("~/Default.aspx", true);
        }
```

When it runs from the VisualStudio it works fine, but when it runs from the IIS I get the The resource cannot be found error.
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable. Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly. Requested URL: /Default.aspx.

That same page is the opening page of the program and when it's called at opening there's no problem.
In debugging I saw that the Page load is activated and the if is entered so the problem is in the Response.Redirect url. I tried taking off the ~/ or just the ~ or doing ../ or /ProgramName//Default.aspx. Nothing is working.

EDIT: My mistake, the problem is NOT in the LOAD event. When running from the IIS the program does NOT make it back to the server, the problem is with the HyperLink NavigateUrl. Attempts to change it doen't help. Any idea?

Comment: Do you run your site on unix ?

Comment: What happens if you replace the line with: `Response.Redirect(Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path), true);`?

Comment: @Aristos Not that I know of.

Comment: There are 2 cases that I think. One, the file system is case sensitive and the file is default.aspx and you call it as Default.aspx, and the second case it to try to make a second redirect from non-secure to secure pages (https<->http) and is not installed correctly.

Answer (score 0):

```
 if (Request.QueryString["Logout"] != null)
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
            Session.Clear();
            Session.Abandon();
            Response.Redirect("~/Default.aspx", false);
        }
```